# How to get a join where the left row is only shown once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a two tables, TableA and TableB. TableB has multiple records for 1 TableA record. If I join the two I get the following:-

```
SELECT TableA.OrderId, TableA.OrderDate, TableB.Description,TableB.Quantity
from TableA
INNER JOIN on TableA.OrderId = TableB.OrderId

TableA.OrderId | TableA.OrderDate | TableB.Description | TableB.Quantity
1              | 24/12/2015       | Banana             | 10 
1              | 24/12/2015       | Apple              | 5
1              | 24/12/2015       | Pear               | 7
1              | 24/12/2015       | Orange             | 3
```

Does anyone know how to get the following output? :-

```
TableA.OrderId | TableA.OrderDate | TableB.Description | TableB.Quantity
1              | 24/12/2015       | Banana             | 10
                                  | Apple              | 5
                                  | Pear               | 7
                                  | Orange             | 3
```

Many hours of fruitless searching with no joy!

Comment: **No, no and once more no.** This is job for application(cell merging/grouping). Of course you can use `ROW_NUMBER OVER(PARTITION BY TableA.OrderId , TableA.OrderDate ORDER BY ...)` and change values to NULL with CASE for rn > 1 for repeating groups to get result as you proposed.

Comment: I agree with lad2025, there is no purpose in doing so, You should do things like this in your frontend.

Comment: Argh, I know I've answered this before but can't find the duplicate.    Anyway, what @lad2025 said.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
create table TableA(OrderId int not null,
OrderDate date null)

insert into TableA Values(1,'12/24/2015')

create table TableB(OrderId int not Null,
Description varchar(50) null,
Quantity int null)

insert into TableB values(1,'Banana',10) 
insert into TableB values(1,'Apple',5)
insert into TableB values(1,'Pear',7)
insert into TableB values(1,'Orange',3)


select case when ttt.RowNum=1 then convert(varchar(50),ttt.OrderId) else '' end,
case when ttt.RowNum=1 then convert(varchar(50),ttt.OrderDate) else '' end,
ttt.Description,
ttt.Quantity
from
(select a.OrderId 
,a.OrderDate
,b.Description,
b.Quantity
,RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.OrderId ORDER BY 1/0) 
 from TableA a join TableB b on a.OrderId=b.OrderId) as ttt
```